# gzip --rsyncable does not zip from java using Runtime.exec()

Tags: gzip, rsync, runtime.exec

I am trying to run `gzip` with the `--rsyncable` option - it works fine when run it in a terminal window (I am on Mac OS) - but it does not work when I run it from java with the following code.

Any idea what the problem could be?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class RsyncIssue {
    public static void printOutput(Process p) throws IOException{
            String ss;
            BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while((ss = inReader.readLine()) != null ){
                    System.out.println("[IN] "+ ss);
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("Test.ext");
        if( !f.exists())
        {
            f.createNewFile();
        }
        String zipCommand = "gzip --rsyncable " + f.getCanonicalPath();
        System.out.println("Zipping file : " + f.getName() );
        System.out.println("Zipping command:  " + zipCommand);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(zipCommand);
        printOutput(p);
        File zipfile = new File(f.getCanonicalPath()+".gz");
        if( !zipfile.exists())
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("zip file does not exist " + zipfile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it throws at - throw new RuntimeException("zip file does not exist " + zipfile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Can you post the stack-trace?

Answer (score 0):

Things you should do:

- Call `p.waitFor()` so that execution blocks until the execution has completed.
- Then call `p.exitValue()` and compare to `0` to see if there was an error.
- In `printOutput` also read the process's `getErrorStream()` to view any errors.
- Check that `--rsyncable` is available on your platform, it is not a universally-available `gzip` option.